# ASP.NET Core 8 Web API not receiving the request body when the content type is set to "application/json"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I am encountering an issue with my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API where the request body is not being received when the content type is set to "application/json".

Despite setting up the API to accept JSON data, the values are not being populated in the corresponding model or parameters. This issue arises despite successful testing in Postman, where the request body appears to be correctly formatted.

I am seeking guidance on identifying the root cause of this problem and finding a resolution to ensure the API properly receives and processes JSON data from client requests. Any insights or troubleshooting steps to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my API:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Login(LoginRequest loginRequest)
{
    // ...
}
```

And this is my Postman request:

[image]

And this is the `LoginRequest` class:

```
public class LoginRequest
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

This is the debugger:

[image]

Comment: Your postman request is a get but your endpoint is a post, change on postman to Post and try again.

Comment: @MauricioAtanache Same issue

Comment: You could try to use frombody attribute : `public HttpResponseMessage Login([FromBody] LoginRequest loginRequest)`

Comment: @Bolo not working :(

Comment: Hi @ManarAl-Zabadani, pls check the `Headers` tab in your postman if it contains correct header. Have your tried default integrated swagger to post the data, does it also not working?

Comment: Dont return HttpResponseMessage, rather return ActionResult, on return statement you just return Ok();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you can try:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginRequest loginRequest)
{
    AuthBusiness bl = new AuthBusiness();
    var user = bl.Login(loginRequest);
    if (user!=null)
    {
        return Ok(user);
    }

    // If failed you return something else, can be not found, not authorized, bad request depending on your validation process.
    return BadRequest(loginRequest);
}
```